# Get the index upon insertion in SplayTreeSet in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, splay-tree

I have a `SplayTreeSet`  in dart and I was wondering wether I could get the position where the object is inserted.

Usually I would know it as `length - 1`, but since in `SplayTreeSet` are sorted, I am not sure the item will end up at the end. Is there a way I could get the index upon insertion without looking for it in a second moment?

Comment: do you mean that [SplayTreeSet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-collection/SplayTreeSet-class.html)? if so, it does not have `indexOf` method

Comment: oh, right sorry, I mean retrieving the index manually (not via indexOf).

Comment: btw what do you need that index for?

Comment: I want to create a custom constant look-up table which is sorted on one property but hashes a different one. So I am storing a different map to map the values i want to hash to the index of the item in the SplayTreeMap.